# PowerBI Cloud - Access dataset from the SQL Server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

In the company we have Power BI Cloud, which is already integrated into other system. I was wondering if we could take advantage of this integration and download data from Power BI Cloud dataset directly to our SQL Server (not the other way around, as is standard). Power BI would be the source of the data, and in that case SQL Server would be the client that would download the data. I found how to load PBI Desktop data to the SQL Server, but not how to use the PBI Cloud datasource. Is it even possible and if yes is there any documentation to that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PowerBI implementation usually works the other way around, you use your infrastructure to prepare your data and get it in shape before consuming it in reports.

That said, you have a few options.

1. As above, move your data prep and processing outside of PowerBI
2. Use [Azure Data Factory to perform your PowerQuery data prep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-power-query-activity) steps outside of PowerBI
3. Use the [PowerBI XMLA endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-connect-tools). This requires the PowerBI premium cloud SKU.
4. Download data manually with the PowerBI export options.

Comment: If it’s under 100,000 rows then this API is a way to export data from Power BI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries

Comment: Yes, @GregGalloway - good point. This API is effectively a wrapper for the XMLA endpoint.

Comment: Thank you both, I will look into these options :-)